# Entity Framework Core RemoveRange() generates multiple DELETE statements under the hood?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework-core

For a long time I was believing that the method Context.RemoveRange() is optimized for multiple rows removal by using single DELETE statement, but today I noticed in my logs that actually per each of entity in the specified range there is executed a separate DELETE statement.

Given the below example:

```
// e.g. 200 entities
var entities = Context.MyTable.Where(x => x.ModificationDate < DateTime.Now).ToList();
Context.RemoveRange(entities);
```

Looking at the logs I've found that it is actually running multiple DELETE statements:

```
2021-08-17 16:07:46.726 +02:00 [INF] Executed DbCommand (3ms) [Parameters=[@p0='?' (DbType = 
Guid)], CommandType='"Text"', CommandTimeout='30']
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DELETE FROM [MyTable]
WHERE [Id] = @p0;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;

2021-08-17 16:07:46.731 +02:00 [INF] Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[@p0='?' (DbType = 
Guid)], CommandType='"Text"', CommandTimeout='30']
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DELETE FROM [MyTable]
WHERE [Id] = @p0;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;
```

I've pasted logs related to only 2 records, but they keep repeating in the log file.

Is there any way I can make the RemoveRange() to run this as a single statement, e.g. DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE ID IN(1, 2)?

Let me mention that I'm not asking for Context.MyTable.FromSqlRaw() or such.
I'd like to know if this is somehow possible with RemoveRange().

I have also tried the following:

```
var ids = new [] { 1, 2 };
var entities = ids.Select(x=> new Entity() { Id = x });
Context.RemoveRange(entities);
```

But there is no difference.

Comment: I have not experimented much with changing the backend behavior of EFCore, however have you tried seeing the result of your db.SaveChanges method? If I remember correctly it returns the number of operations or changes it executes.

Maybe you could experiment with different DbContext options and see if you can lower this value. Or, use extensions like someone else suggested.

Answer (score 3):

Please take a look.

"The number of statements that EF batches in a single roundtrip depends on the database provider being used. For example, performance analysis has shown batching to be generally less efficient for SQL Server when less than 4 statements are involved. Similarly, the benefits of batching degrade after around 40 statements for SQL Server, so EF Core will by default only execute up to 42 statements in a single batch, and execute additional statements in separate roundtrips."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-nz/ef/core/performance/efficient-updating

Comment: I just ran a test on one of my programs that generated 100 separate delete statements. That project is stuck on EF 6.4.4. On a different project that was also in EF 6.4.4 territory, I used the N.EntityFramework.Extensions that has bulk operations.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of [extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/) that can make this operation effective. I would suggest to use [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore) (disclaimer: I'm one of the creators)

Then deleting become easy:

```cs
var affected = Context.MyTable
   .Where(x => x.ModificationDate < DateTime.Now)
   .Delete();
```

Comment: Thanks, that is a nice option, however I would still like to know whether it is possible to achieve with RemoveRange().

Comment: Well, then It is the question for EF Core developers.