# Alternative to LINQ RemoveRange in EF 6

Tags: c#, .net

I have two tables, Transactions and TransactionsStaging.
I am using a LINQ query to fetch all rows in TransactionsStaging which have a duplicate in Trasactions and then removing them form TranscationsStaging.  So ultimately I am removing all entries in TransactionsStaging which have a duplicate in Transactions table.

I have produced the following so far:

```
            IEnumerable<WebApi.Models.TransactionStaging> result = (from ts in db.TransactionsStaging
                            join t in db.Transactions
                            on ts.Description equals t.Description
                          select ts).ToList();
            db.TransactionsStaging.RemoveRange(result);
            db.SaveChanges();
```

The above works, but when inspecting the actual SQL queries being sent to the DB, I noticed that the RemoveRange produces a SQL DELETE statement for each row it is removing.

Is there a way to accomplish the same but avoid the multiple delete statements?

I wanted to explore this possibility before switching to executing a raw SQL statement rather than using Linq and ORM.

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68821293/entity-framework-core-removerange-generates-multiple-delete-statements-under-t I think the answer is presented there.

Comment: @PaulSinnema I also came across that answer, but unfortunately it suggests using a third party extension.  I am curious to know if it can be achieved within EF Core itself.

Comment: Given that the third party decided to write an extension that specifically does this, I doubt that it is built into EF6.

Comment: Executing a Raw SQL Query is another option.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/raw-sql

Comment: @MusaffarPatel You could always write your own LINQ extension if you wanted to. But the extension offered does the job, I think.

Comment: @RobertHarvey No Robert, come on, we've had our share of SQL strings in code. It's cumbersome, error prone, and subject to SQL injection. Not a good alternative.

Comment: None of those disadvantages apply if you do it correctly.  EF is not a 100% solution; it never was.  That's why Raw SQL queries exist in EF (EF Core still has this capability).

Comment: The `FromSqlInterpolated` and `ExecuteSqlInterpolated` methods allow using string interpolation syntax in a way that protects against SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Come on guys, that's the last straw. There are lot's of better solutions out there.

Comment: *{shrug}* The `SqlQuery` and `ExecuteSQL` statements already parameterize properly anyway.

Comment: @PaulSinnema I only see one viable solution which is to use the 3rd party extension.  It's a shame that a primitive operation like delete suffers from this drawback.  I don't see a problem using raw SqlQuery here if as Robert suggested statements are parameterized.   I was already aware of the extension and decided in favour of a SQL query instead prior to posting the question.

Comment: @PaulSinnema: Like you, I've developed a semi-automatic negative response to seeing strings in code, and I really love how LINQ makes queries more composable. But it's a little over the top to act like direct SQL is a completely unacceptable solution, especially when the alternative requires adding a dependency on a third-party library--that introduces a whole different set of problems, which might matter more to many people than the problems inherent in using strings.

Comment: I'm stopping the discussion here. Do whatever you wanna do.

Comment: Is your problem explicitly that it's executing multiple statements or that executing all of those statements serially takes too long?  If the latter, you can (relatively) easily parallelize the operations.  If so, lmk and I'll whip up an answer

Comment: @Moho - the problem is that I could be deleting hundreds of rows and it simply doesn't seem effective to send a query for each one when single a sql delete statement can accomplish the same result

Answer (score 1):

If you want to issue only a single database command, either a stored proc or raw SQL statements would be the way to go, since EntityFramework does not support bulk transactions.

You could go with a variety of bulk extensions available for batch operations.

Comment: I'm totally against this. Read my comment to Robert in the post of the OP.

Comment: @PaulSinnema The `FromSqlInterpolated` and `ExecuteSqlInterpolated` methods allow using string interpolation syntax in a way that protects against SQL injection attacks.